# Set initial page number on the header of Excel file with a number greater than 32767

Tags: excel, vba

Set initial page number on the header of Excel file with a number greater than 32767

I have 3 huge excel sheet that have to be printed with page number on the header. The first excel has 35.000 pages. I need to set the initial page number on the header of the second sheet to 35.001 but when I try to set the initial page number to a value greater than 32767 an error occurs.
I try to use VBA but I can't add any integer to the page number on the header:

```
sub test()
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&P+35000"
end sub
```

The only result I got was append "35000" to a page number.

Error: "Integer not valid"

Comment: I have to ask: why on earth would you print a 35000+ page worksheet?

Answer (score 1):

The largest number for the page number is an integer, which in Excel cannot be bigger than 32767. But if you set up a Long in VBA, you can feed it to the page setup

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim StartPage As Long

StartPage = 35000

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .FirstPageNumber = StartPage
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
End Sub
```

[image]